# How can I make it so that instead of weed divide 100 it would be weed divide by the total weeds everyone pulled?

Tags: python

```
kids = []
count = 0
for kids in range(0,8):
  kids = input("Enter kid: ")
  kids = kids.lower()
  weed = int(input("How many weeds did they pull: "))
  for i in weed:
   count = count + weed
   num = weed/100*100 #How can I make it so that instead of weed divide 100 it would be weed divide by the total weeds everyone pulled?
   print ("$", num)
```

How can I make it so that instead of weed divide 100 it would be weed divide by the total weeds everyone pulled at the end?

Comment: `for i in weed:`: how does that work?

Comment: Why do you have the `for i in weed` loop?

Comment: @TomDalton indeed

Answer (score 0):

```
kids = []
count = 0
list_weed = []
for kids in range(0,3):
    kids = input("Enter kid: ")
    kids = kids.lower()
    weed = int(input("How many weeds did they pull: "))
    list_weed.append(weed)
for i in list_weed:
    print("$",i/sum(list_weed)*100)
```

even though the code you made makes no sense, that's how you make it work.

```
Enter kid: a
How many weeds did they pull: 3
Enter kid: b
How many weeds did they pull: 6
Enter kid: g
How many weeds did they pull: 10
$ 15.789473684210526
$ 31.57894736842105
$ 52.63157894736842
```

***It is a percentage not a money amount, but the code is made as the OP's wants***

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
kids = []
count = 0
totalweed = 0
for kids in range(0,8):
  kids = input("Enter kid: ")
  kids = kids.lower()
  weed = int(input("How many weeds did they pull: "))
  totalweed += weed
  count = count + weed
  num = weed/totalweed*100 
  print ("$", num)
```

Comment: I don't think this code is right `from for i in weed:` onwards

Comment: This is still wrong, the `print ("$", num)` stuff doesnt make sense inside the loop.

Comment: `i in weed` gives an error because weed is an integer not an array so you can't get an index from it.

Comment: weed is assigned an integer value so it wont work. However that doesn't matter as it answers the problem in the question .